# Criar telas de carregamento visuais em python

Tags: python

Como essa:

|-----     |
    90%

Onde ela carrega nos segundos que eu especificar. Somente para uso visual, pois eu quero fazer um efeito somente estético :)

Onde as linhas são os extremos da barra de carregamento e os hífens o progresso, onde eu quero que exiba em baixo a porcentagem de conclusão

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com). Uma boa prática para iniciarmos uma discussão saudável é fazer o [tour], caso tenha feito, leia o guia de [ask]. Comece seguindo estas recomendações, principalmente sabendo quais os tipos de perguntas deve fazer, como criar um exemplo mínimo que seja completo e verificável e até mesmo o que fazer quando alguém te responder.

Comment: Em interface de comando (CLI) ou realmente quer janelas?

Answer (score 1):

Usei o caracter '#' ao invés do '-' que é o padrão, codigo abaixo, rode em uma console para ver o resultado, adapte a função `test()` para seu contexto.

```
import time

def progress_bar(done):
    print("\rProgress: [{0:50s}] {1:.1f}%".format('#' * int(done * 50), done * 100),end='')

def test():
    for n in range(101):
        progress_bar(n/100)
        time.sleep(1)


test()      
Progress: [####################                             ] 20.0%
```